# Iter to get the badge "Work with Google Assistant"

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, badge

I need to create a Google Actions Custom (Dialogflow + Google Assistant) to interact with devices.

My customer would like to get the Work with Google Assistant badge. What should I do? How long does it take to get certified?

Thanks,
Nino

Answer (score 0):

The Works With Google Assistant badge is primarily used for smart home devices that integrate with the Google Assistant through [the Smart Home platform](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/overview). Dialogflow is generally not going to be the best way to create your integration.

The [smart home documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/launching) provides guidance on the launch and certification process.